# CSS Image Scaling in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

I'm facing a bit of an odd problem with CSS formatting on Internet Explorer and Firefox. For a navigation bar, I have several images that I want to display in a column, with a background image. To accomplish this, I positioned the background image on the page, then made a div inside it to hold each image link, and used CSS to format each image. Works great in Safari, but in IE and Firefox, the images don't scale to the size they need to be to fit the background image.

The relevant CSS from my page is here:

```
.nav_background_home{
width:17%;
position:absolute;
left:56%;
top:31%;
z-index:100;}


.nav_background_home .nav_items{
position:absolute;
top:8%;
z-index:150;}


img.nav_item{
margin-bottom:3.75%;
height:4.4%;
margin-left:7%;}
```

I then added everything in the HTML:

```
<div class="nav_background_home"><img src="nav_background.png" width=100% />
<div class="nav_items">
    <img src="nav_items/set_design.png" class="nav_item" height=100% />
    <img src="nav_items/company_report.png" class="nav_item" height=100% style="height:4.1%;"/>
    <img src="nav_items/prompt_pages.png" class="nav_item" height=100% />
    <img src="nav_items/characters.png" class="nav_item" height=100% />
    <img src="nav_items/costumes.png" height=100% class="nav_item" style="margin-bottom:2%;" />
    <img src="nav_items/video.png" height=100% class="nav_item" style="height:4.1%;" />

</div>
```

This works flawlessly in Safari, but in Firefox and IE, the images refuse to scale. I already tried removing the "height=100%" from the HTML, but that doesn't change anything. The site is here, if that helps: http://gilmannews.com/rishi/sandbox.html .

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What should fit into what?

Answer (score 0):

It should be height="100%" and width="100%" try that to start.

Also, try running it through http://validator.w3.org/check

This will show you all kinds of little problems that some browsers might handle nicely, but others won't